# Has anyone found a workaround for nesting views in React Native on Android?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Hey I was wondering if there was some kind of workaround for nesting views on React Native on android, it seems that things like

`class BlueIsCool extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>
        There is a blue square
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
        in between my text.
      </Text>
    );
  }
}`

is not possible on Android. Is there any way to do something like this on Android using React Native?

Comment: you can nest like this <View><Text></Text><View>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may simply do

```
<View>
    <Text>
        There is a blue square
    </Text>
    <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
    <Text>
        in between my text.
    </Text>
</View>
```