# Error in Android: Nesting of View within Text is not supported on Android

Tags: android, ios, text, react-native

I am doing with React Native. My UI is like this:

[image]

It 's ok in IOS but in Android, error:

> Nesting of View within Text is not supported on Android

Codes:

```
<Text style={styles.text}>
            {'I am a '}
            <Text
              style={styles.text_hili}
              onPress={() => this.showPopupDialog()}>
              {this.state.text_year}
              {this._renderIcon()}
            </Text>
            .....
```

```
_renderIcon = () => {
    return <Icon style={styles.icon} type='font-awesome' name={'chevron-down'} size={25} color="white" />
  }
```

Anybody got this issue. Thanks a lot. If this is a limitation of Android (nested views), how to work around for this situation.

Comment: it is work on my project. you can try text components between View components.

Comment: @RoShan I am also facing exactly same issue. Did you get any solution? I need some approach from you. Bcz my design also looks similar.

Comment: I don't work with react native any more. I have just search and found this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43174856/has-anyone-found-a-workaround-for-nesting-views-in-react-native-on-android. You can try this